# How to convert query string http://example.com/myview?page=1 to http://example.com/myview/page/1 in views?

Tags: views, paging

I have to make url of views seo friendly. I need to convert query string http://example.com/myview?page=1 to http://example.com/myview/page/1.

Can you please suggest, how can i do this.

Comment: Not an answer, but you can use example.com instead of calling test.com in your example URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the module: Query parameter to url(https://www.drupal.org/project/query_parameters_to_url), It will work for you.

Just specify the pattern {^myview} inside **/admin/config/search/query-parameters-to-url** after installing and activating the module.

Let me know if any helps needed.